# How can a tidal height be lower than 'Chart Datum'/'LAT' e.g 'Lowest Astronomical Tide'?

Tags: sea-level, mapping, tides

We just had a very low low tide in the UK, an equinoctial tide on the 12th of March that was calculated as -0.13m above chart datum, i.e 13cm below the 'Lowest Astronomical Tide'.

Check here for tidal heights- https://ntslf.org/tides/hilo

How can a tide be lower than the 'Lowest Astronomical Tide' on a chart?

Comment: air pressure and wind will do that.

Comment: Interesting…some of these tide heights appear to be predicted years/decades in advance…can air pressure and wind on a particular day be accurately predicted that far in advance?